# Prevent windows from presenting any dialog on native code unhandled exception

Tags: c++, windows

Our buildserver compiles and runs testsuites for many different c++ programs. From time to time the programs are buggy, and can crash.

When they crash, Windows7 will always throw this modal dialog:

[image]

Which has to be clicked away by a human being, causing the buildserver to sit idle.

Is there a way to at a system level prevent this from happening?
I know I can do it from within the process itself, but I'd love to be able to do it across the entire system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `WerAddExcludedApplication` should do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513617.aspx

Or read more about Windows error reporting in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513636.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Refer to "Disabling Dr.Watson in Windows 7" http://xheo.com/blog/disabling-dr-watson-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

You might try these lines at the start of your `main.cpp`:

```
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
```

Read more about these APIs here: [_CrtSetReportMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y71x448.aspx) and [_CrtSetReportFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a68f826y.aspx).

Good luck!

Edit: Oops, not exactly what you were asking for. Oh well...